# How to align figure in .tex file side by side?

Tags: graphics, positioning, subfloats

I have used `\subfigure` to align figure side by side. The figure is a graph and is in `.tex` file form. Thus instead of using `\includegraphics`, i have used `\input`. The problem is the graph is in different line as seen in attached picture using the following code. Can it be placed side by side? Do i have to convert tex file in pdf?

```
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{subfigure}[b] {-1\linewidth} 
    \input{fig1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\linewidth}
    \input{fig2}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{ABC}
\end{figure*}
```

UPDATE: The graph is created using gnuplot and converted to .tex file

[image: This is the output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do not use the full line width, but only a fraction (2 line widths do not fit into one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You should use only a fraction of the line width as width of the individual subfigures.

Example:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth} 
    \input{fig1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \input{fig2}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{ABC}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried with 0.4 but the figures were in different lines. So I went with a weird number as 1 and -1 to check what it happens. It works .  It would be awesome if you can point me to the documentation or elaborate on use of linewidth.

Comment: @Sohil There is no documentation that would describe any further use: subfigure takes a length as its argument. `\linewidth` is the length determining the width of the current line and a factor before that scales this length.